# Can't use vector drawable as a a bitmap drawable in android

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I am packing a vector drawable in a bitmap drawable and trying to use it as background for a view.This complies successfully but crashes during run time with Resource Not Found exception.

Here is the resource xml files:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_fruit_salad"
    android:tileMode="disabled"
    android:gravity="center">
</bitmap>
```

Where @drawable/ic_fruit_salad is a vector resource.

The xml for layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/rv_listofitems"
     android:background="@drawable/background_fruit_salad"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

But if vector resource is used directly it works fine.The reason I am packing in a bitmap is not to stretch the bitmap when used as background for the view.I know there might be some other methods to achieve this , but I am wondering why this doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because a vector drawable is not a bitmap.

Comment: But aren't vector drawables supposed scale easily without loosing quality to any dimensions unlike bitmaps?

Comment: "But aren't vector drawables supposed scale easily without loosing quality to any dimensions unlike bitmaps?" -- yes, so long as you are taking into account any aspect ratio that may be intrinsic to the path inside the vector.

Comment: But when I use it directly it works and doesn't maintain any aspect ratio (means it stretches) , so I think that might not be an issue.But I am not an expert in it.

Answer (score 2):

Creating equivalent png files of your vector asset is helpful. Use *File->New->Image Asset* menu and set your vector drawable address in the path.